# JQuery append doesn't load css for toggle button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to use a toggle button with jquery appended content. The appended content uses Labelauty jQuery Plugin to load the check boxes and its working fine.
But the toggle button is not loading the relevant css properly.

Here is my html code for the panel which includes the toggle button.

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="panel">
   <div class="panel-body container-fluid">
   <div id="testcases" class="accordion js-accordion">
   <h4>Test<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i> <small>CASES</small>
   <div class="toggle-wrap w-checkbox">
   <input class="toggle-ticker w-checkbox-input" data-ix="toggle-switch" data-name="Toggle Switch" id="Toggle-Switch" name="Toggle-Switch" type="checkbox" onclick="toggle()">
    <label class="toggle-label w-form-label" for="Toggle-Switch">           </label>
    <div class="toggle">
    <div class="toggle-active">
    <div class="active-overlay"></div>
    <div class="top-line"></div>
    <div class="bottom-line"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   </h4>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info float-right" onclick="loadplan()">Add to Plan</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--TestPlan Panel-->
<div class="Panel">
<div class="col-md-13">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-body container-fluid">   
  
      <h4>Test<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i> <small>PLAN</small></h4>
      <!-- Start list -->
      <ul id="testplan" class="list-group"></ul>          
      </div>
      <!-- End list -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which output this

[before jquery append](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WywW5.png)

Here is my jquery to append content

```js
//Load TestCase List to Accordion
var testSuiteList;
var currentTestSuite;

function loadtestcases(testSuite, testcases) {
  currentTestSuite = testSuite;
  var testcases = testcases.split(",");
  // $("#testcases").empty();
  $("#testcases div:not(:first)").remove();
  var id = 0;
  // $("#testcases").append("<h4>Test<i class='fa fa-thumbs-o-down'></i> <small>CASES</small></h4>")
  testcases.forEach(function(entry) {
    id = id + 1;
    $("#testcases").append("<div class='accordion__item js-accordion-item'>" +
      "<div class='accordion-header js-accordion-header'>" +
      "<input type=\"checkbox\" class='to-labelauty-icon' name=\"inputLableautyNoLabeledCheckbox\" data-plugin=\"labelauty\" data-label=\"false\" id=\"labelauty-" + id + "\" value=\"" + entry + "\"> " + entry + "</div>" +
      "<div class='accordion-body js-accordion-body'>" +
      "<div class='accordion-body__contents'>" +
      "data-table" +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>" +
      "<div class='accordion__item js-accordion-item active'>" +
      "</div>")
  });

  //accordion js for appended div
  var accordion = (function() {

    var $accordion = $('.js-accordion');
    var $accordion_header = $accordion.find('.js-accordion-header');
    var $accordion_item = $('.js-accordion-item');

    // default settings 
    var settings = {
      // animation speed
      speed: 400,

      // close all other accordion items if true
      oneOpen: false
    };

    return {
      // pass configurable object literal
      init: function($settings) {
        $accordion_header.on('click', function() {
          accordion.toggle($(this));
        });

        $.extend(settings, $settings);

        // ensure only one accordion is active if oneOpen is true
        if (settings.oneOpen && $('.js-accordion-item.active').length > 1) {
          $('.js-accordion-item.active:not(:first)').removeClass('active');
        }

        // reveal the active accordion bodies
        $('.js-accordion-item.active').find('> .js-accordion-body').show();
      },
      toggle: function($this) {

        if (settings.oneOpen && $this[0] != $this.closest('.js-accordion').find('> .js-accordion-item.active > .js-accordion-header')[0]) {
          $this.closest('.js-accordion')
            .find('> .js-accordion-item')
            .removeClass('active')
            .find('.js-accordion-body')
            .slideUp()
        }

        // show/hide the clicked accordion item
        $this.closest('.js-accordion-item').toggleClass('active');
        $this.next().stop().slideToggle(settings.speed);
      }
    }
  })();

  $(document).ready(function() {
    accordion.init({
      speed: 300,
      oneOpen: true
    });
    $(":checkbox").labelauty({
      label: false
    });
  });
}

//Load the selected testcases on TestPlan
function loadplan() {
  currentTestSuite;
  //Map the selected testcases to an array
  var selectedtclist = [];
  $('input[class="to-labelauty-icon labelauty"]:checked').each(function() {
    selectedtclist.push(this.value);
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < selectedtclist.length; i++) {
    var tc_name = selectedtclist[i];

    var searchWord = currentTestSuite + " " + "|" + " " + tc_name;
    // see if element(s) exists that matches by checking length
    var exists = $('#testplan li:contains(' + searchWord + ')').length;

    if (!exists) {
      //Append selected testcases to TestPlan
      $("#testplan").append("<li class='list-group-item list-group-item-info'>" + currentTestSuite + " " + "|" + " " + tc_name + "</li>");
    }
  };
};
```

which output this

[after loading jquery appended content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bHjv.png)

How can I load the styles for toggle button properly?

Comment: Where are you applying the styles? Have you tried to load the styles before, with the page? or you could add jQuery that apply the style to the element (but it will render after the element is display!) or you could add inline styling (which I hate, but solve issues sometimes...)

Answer (score 0):

You use `append()` for the selector `$("#testplan")`, but I cannot find that ID `id="testplan"` for any element in your HTML code, so therefore JS can't find it and thus cannot "appand" anything to it.

Comment: I have only copied part of the html code, Now I have edited the post to include full html code. Please have a look at that

Comment: Ok got the css to load properly, I had to put the line
<div id="testcases" class="accordion js-accordion">
after h4 tag. but since the input type is checkbox labelauty plugin is applying its styles over that toogle button

Comment: If you use the "jquery-labelauty.css" it should not do that, since all depending on the class ".labelauty" for inputs ([as long you mean this one](https://github.com/fntneves/jquery-labelauty/blob/master/source/jquery-labelauty.css))

Comment: Btw. did you fix the append issue? Have you tried ["jQuery html"](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of "append" for testing? Something like > $("#testplan").html($("#testplan").html() + '<li>New Entry</li>') ?

Comment: Yes both the append and styles issue are fixed now. Thanks Parker. No I haven't tried JQuery html. I will have a look at that.